# django-rest-framework PUT manytomany through model

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a Django Model w/ a m2m relationship that uses a through model:

## models.py

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    other_models = models.ManyToManyField("ModelA", through="ModelC")

class ModelC(models.Model):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey("ModelA", related_name="link_to_model_a")
    model_b = models.ForeignKey("ModelB", related_name="link_to_model_b")
    some_other_info = models.TextField()
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("model_a", "model_b", )
```

I want to serialize this using django-rest-framework:

## serializers.py

```
class ModelCSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelC
        fields = ('id', 'model_a', 'model_b', 'some_other_info', )

class QModelBSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = ('id', 'other_models', )
    other_models = ModelCSerializer(many=True, required=False, source="link_to_model_b")
```

Now, for existing models the GET displays properly:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "i am an instance of model_b",
  "other_models": [
    {"id": 1, "model_a": 1,"model_b": 2, "some_other_info":"here is some other info"}
  ],
}
```

But, if I try to PUT some data it fails w/ a unique_together error.  I thought that sending this as a PUT would cause an update (which shouldn't raise a unique_together error) not a create?  Here is the code for PUT:

## views.py

```
class ModelBDetail(APIView):
    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        model = ModelB.objects.get(id=pk)
        serializer = ModelBSerializer(model, data=request.data, context={"request": request})
        if serializer.is_valid():  # THIS IS RETURNING FALSE
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you PUT the GET result as you posted it?

Comment: @Ivan - Yes, no changes.

Answer (score 1):

Django rest framework documentation states that it is up to developer to implement [creates and updates for nested representations](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations).

Answer (score 0):

Although @Ivan was correct about writing my own create & update fn, the specific issue I was seeing was that the nested serialization did not have an instance attribute associated with it.

The new code looks like this:

## serializers.py

```
class ModelBSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    ....

    def update(self, model_instance, validated_data):
        model_c_serializer = self.fields["other_models"]

        model_c_data = validated_data.pop(model_c_serializer.source, [])

        for key, value in validated_data.iteritems():
            setattr(model_instance, key, value)
        model_instance.save()

        model_c_serializer.update(model_instance.link_to_model_b.all(),
model_c_data)

        return model_instance

class ModelCSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    ...

    def to_internal_value(self, data):

        # this is as good a place as any to set the instance
        try:
            model_class = self.Meta.model
            self.instance = model_class.objects.get(pk=data.get("id"))
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass

        return super(ModelCSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)
```

Basically, I call `update` for the nested serializers explicitly and I also force each nested serializer to check the data that is passed to them for an instance.